# Python html в качестве результата

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi

Добрый день, подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли так сделать.

Есть функция типа

```
def application(environ, start_response):
   status = '200 OK'
   output = 'Pg!'

   response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                    ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
   start_response(status, response_headers)
   return [output]
```

Нужно чтобы как результат выполнения программы  была html-страница, типа return [ссылка на страницу] как-то так. Программа запускается при помощи uwsgi с использованием nginx . Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Так вам редирект может нужен?

Как-то вы все запутали, говорите - нужна страница, а возвращаете ссылку на нее, а не саму страницу.

Comment: Может конечно я неправильно задачу ставлю, я хочу сгенерировать html-cтраницу, средствами python, типа есть шаблон откуда берётся основа, потом по обстоятельствам этот шаблон заполняется. Как-то так. Если я неправильно мыслю, то поправте меня.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно написать функцию, которая на вход получает адрес html-файла и возвращает его содержимое. Как-то так:

```
def readFile(filename):
    f = open(filename)
    content = f.read()
    f.close()
    return content
```

Теперь можно передавать на выход функции `application` результат выполнения этой функции:

```
return [readFile(file_address)]
```

Также в функции `readFile` можно организовать какую-нибудь обработку html-файла, сделав подобие шаблонизатора.

Comment: Вы правы, сейчас понял, что мне нужно, спасибо!